# Is there a rotational equivalent to newtons laws?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Newtons three laws of motion appears to apply only for linear motion:

> 1. An object remains at rest or moves in a straight line at uniform velocity unless a force is applied.
> 2. Force is mass times acceleration.
> 3. Every action causes an equal and opposite reaction.

Is there a rotational equivalence? For example:

> 1'. Every body rotates around a fixed axis at uniform angular velocity unless a torque is applied
>
> 2'. Torque is Moment of Inertia times angular acceleration
>
> 3'. When one body exerts a torque on another; there is an equal and opposite torque applied on the first body by the second.

First are these actually correct; if not, what are the correct equivalence; and who formulated them?

Comment: Everything that's true in classical mechanics derives from the basic formulations of classical mechanics, of course. In your rotation laws, you speak of objects which are no just points. Maybe have a look at [Newton–Euler equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Euler_equations) and [Euler's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_%28rigid_body_dynamics%29) (Wikipedia).

Comment: Mechanics has a long history; I recall reading somewhere that ideas of Torque go back to Archimedes work on levers.

Comment: That's a trivial "No". The first sentence is simply not true, as even a cursory look at the physics of rigid rotating bodies will show. Most irregular bodies will actually present a chaotic tumbling motion.

Comment: @curiousOne: what about conservation of angular momentum?

Comment: @CuriousOne: You say "not true", but I feel you can bend the meaning of the words in the formulation to make it fit. It might be worth it to point out that there are funky things like [the tennis racket theorem](https://youtu.be/L2o9eBl_Gzw). That's why I said we must keep in mind that however we (re-)formulate the statements here, it must correspond to some truths in classical mechanics. The interesting question would be that if we take the stance to take the resulting statements as axioms, how much must we add to get Newton back. PS, Ullah: I'd not trouble myself with Newton too much.

Comment: That angular momentum is conserved follows from the symmetry of space under rotation, just like momentum conservation follows directly from the symmetry under translation. Generally speaking, Newton's laws are a simple introduction to classical mechanics, but they are not all there is in classical mechanics. The better way to approach it is actually from different sets of axioms, after which Newton's laws become an important special case.

Comment: @curiousOne: I'm aware of the Hamiltonian and lagrangian approach to classical mechanics; and how this links in with the formalism of QM if not GR.

Comment: Historically though, Newtons Laws were important in formulating classical mechanics; hence the question.

Comment: @NikolajK: You can't make something work that can be experimentally falsified by throwing a brick into the air. It is simply not true for even the most trivial cases of rotation that a rotating body will have a stable axis of rotation in the absence of an external torque.

Comment: I agree, Newton made an important contribution to physics, but he made only one contribution of many. That we are teaching Newton's laws in high school and not Hamiltonian mechanics, which is far more important, has nothing to do with physics. It's an artifact of the limited mathematical training of students at that stage.

Comment: @curiousone: that observation makes sense; but doesn't angular momentum have an axis? Are you saying that in the absence of external torque that this axis can change direction?

Comment: @curiousone: I can't say I agree; newtons laws are easily understood and visualisable in a way that the Hamiltonian formalism isn't; plus it's follows the historical progression; and one can see how ideas are not deduced but equally important induced.

Comment: The rotational properties of a rigid body are being described by a a symmetric three-by-three tensor, and that's why one axis of rotation is, in general, unstable. Your first assumption about angular momentum and axes of rotation is simply naive.

Comment: You don't have to agree. One can derive quantum mechanics and quantum field theory more or less directly from Lagrange and Hamilton, but no such thing is possible with Newton. The proof is in the pudding and Newton simply doesn't cut the mustard, as they say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There *is* a rotational equivalence, but it is not what you stated. The problem, as pointed out by @curiousOne, is that conservation of angular momentum does NOT imply rotation about the same (fixed) axis. But I think a simple restatement like this could work:

- if no torque acts on a body, its angular momentum will remain unchanged
- rate of change of angular momentum is proportional to applied net torque
- when two bodies interact, the torque that A applies to B is equal and opposite to the torque that B applies to A, so that the angular momentum of the combined system (A+B) is preserved.

I believe that addresses the objections raised to your earlier version. Note that "axis of rotation is unchanged" is fundamentally different from "angular momentum is unchanged".

Comment: Possibly, but all of that, and much more, is trivially covered by Noether. The bigger problem is that I am not sure that there is an easy way to derive the actual dynamics of rotating bodies from the above axioms. The third statement is also problematic, because of the coupling of orbital angular momentum and spin, which makes for an extremely ugly analysis of the dynamics of two coupled rigid rotators. It's probably the latter that prevents us from axiomatizing rotating motions this way.

Comment: @CuriousOne - this question is tagged "classical-mechanics". What coupling of angular momentum and spin are you talking about in the classical context?

Comment: The one that increases the length of the day on Earth while moving the moon further away. That's the classical equivalent of orbital angular momentum and spin coupling and it's totally non-trivial as the astronomers can tell.

Comment: Does "axis of rotation" in the first and the last paragraph mean the axis in the reference frame of the rotating object (e.g. a line between two painted dots on the object) or in the reference frame of an external non-rotating observer (e.g. a line between two painted dots on the lab where the object is rotating)?

Comment: It would have to be "in an external frame" - but I can't read the mind of the person who wrote it. Which is why my answer doesn't explicitly speak of an axis - just of "angular momentum" (which, being a vector, is only constant if both magnitude and direction are constant).

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense in connecting linear motion to rotational via a momentum. I obviously have insufficient clarity about what angular momentum is; my assumption was that it's a vector or (pseudo-vector - what-ever this is) whose direction is the axis of rotation; so constancy of angular momentum means constancy of the axis of rotation; given what you said - then this can't follow and the axis of rotation is not aligned with it.

Comment: Rotating about an axis that is not an axis of symmetry results in internal torques and precession of the apparent axis of rotation - hence the comments about "tumbling" etc. angular momentum is conserved. Google "Euler angles".